# How to enable external tool using API for course that was installed at account level

Tags: canvas-lms, lti

I've installed an LTI tool into my canvas-lms as at an account level, but I want to use the canvas data API to programatically enable/disable the tool in specific courses.

How do I enable the navigation placement for  a tool defined at the account level for a specific course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this by managing the availability and the order of specific tabs within the course itself.

Navigation order and hidden/visible can be edited using the [Tabs API PUT](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/tabs.html) method.

You'll first need to get all of the tab ids, then identify which one is associated with the external tool, then use the API to either move or enable/disable them respectively.

Comment: I gave it a try and that seems to work for my needs, thanks again.

Comment: Hey Tabs APIs are of course level. is there any way to do it while adding app using LTI-2? or on account lever?

Comment: No, not really, and LTI2 is dead(ish)  it is being replaced with LTI1.3+Advantage, but within this new specification I don't believe you can set the tab order without using the course level API referenced above.